# Heroku - MacOS Toolbest - multiple heroku accounts ssh key problems

Tags: git, ssl, heroku, key

despite having followed a number of the multi-account manager solutions already published here, both git and heroku seem to be using only the default id_rsa.pub key rather than the keys assigned by the accounts plugin.

```
$heroku version
heroku-toolbelt/2.39.4 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3

$ heroku accounts
my-prod
my-staging
my-dev

$ heroku git:clone  my-test-app-3027 --account my-prod
Cloning from app 'my-test-app-3027'...
Cloning into 'my-test-app-3027'...
Permission denied (publickey).
```

yet,
$ heroku keys --account my-prod

```
=== prod.heroku@my-domain.com Keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...6OVP9KRjNj prod.heroku@my-domain.com
```

is the same key as "~/.ssh/identity.heroku.my-prod.pub

Comment: trace: built-in: git 'fetch'
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@heroku.com' 'git-upload-pack '\''<APP>.git'\'''

 !  Your key with fingerprint 4b:94:aa:04:25:f0:ba:ee:ec:d8:95:2d:16:2c:3c:a4 is not authorized to access <APP>

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that:

- your ~/.ssh/config does contain something along the lines of:

```
Host heroku.example
 HostName heroku.com
 User prod.heroku@my-domain.com 
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity.heroku.my-prod.pub
```

- your `git remote` url used by heroku is something like:

```
    ssh://heroku.example:my-test-app-3027
```

(note the scp syntax here, with `heroku.example` being one of the Host entries of the ssh config file.)

You can also have a look at a heroku account manager like [heroku_plus](https://github.com/bkuhlmann/heroku_plus), and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks for the pointers -- still not quite working, and some further notes:  (1)I am using https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts plugin.  (2)just noticed that it put the wrong permissions on ~/.ssh/config  (3) all heroku commands appear to be working with the exception of "heroku git" ... I will look more at the URL being used by GIT