# Multiple login details

Tags: git, authentication, heroku, github

I am very new to git. I have used it a little bit with GitHub, and following the tutorial for setting git up there was very easy. In doing so, I believe I set global login details for git. And the tutorial was simple to follow, but never really gave me a great understanding of what exactly was happening.

Now, however, I am wanting to use heroku for some app development but I find I cannot clone my app from the repo on heroku.com as I don't have the authentication set up, and I am not entirely sure what to do. I have tried googling, but I haven't managed to find much that is useful to me. I may well be using the wrong search terms, but being new to git I am not totally familiar with all the terminology anyway.

Does setting the global authentication settings for github mean I can only access github remote repos? Is there a way I can set up domain specific authentication? I'm assuming the answer is yes, and if so how is this done?

Thanks in advance for any assistance. I would really like to learn git as it's probably the most useful source control to know about atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "global authentication settings" GitHub asks you to set up are:

- [your username](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git)
- [your email](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git)

Those are necessary for GitHub to recognize your commits as done by yourself, but are in no way unique to GitHub: you can reuse those same username and email for other git repos hosting provider.

For Heroku, at least reuse the same email address for your Heroku account login.

And then follow the "[Getting Started with Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart)" page.
The authentication is done [through ssh keys](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) (and you should generate keys just for heroku).

Since you can also use ssh for GitHub (but you don't have to: https url works just fine), your question could be: "How to maintain multiple ssh keys for multiple services?", you can use an **`~/.ssh/config`** file to register the name and location of different keys.

See for instance:

- "[multiple heroku accounts ssh key problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17540865/6309)"
- "[Git Incorrect SSH Key (Pushing to Heroku)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19195591/6309)"